# plugins for WordPress that allow anonymous users to post entries

Tags: wordpress

Are there any plugins for WordPress that allow users to create blog posts without registering and logging in?

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser. I've changed the wording to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/)

Comment: doesn't exist, link's broken

Answer (score 3):

You can always use comment function / plugin?
And then you can display the comments as posts (styling-wise)

Here are some links you can look at:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/259663
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posthaste/

Answer (score 2):

IndyPress is what you are probably searching for. 
https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/indypress/

It has been written for open publishing sites.
Note: I am biased, as I am one of the developers

Comment: Thanks for disclosing your affiliation with the project. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just have this plugin :
"uCan" 
The way to allow your users, and even guests, to create posts/content on your WordPress-based site. uCan post adds a configurable submission form to a page on your site allowing users to contribute content to your site. The best part about this is that your users/guests don't have to access the dashboard. With just a handful of simple yet powerful settings you can have this all setup in under 3 minutes. uCan Post imitates the regular WordPress post/page editor and even allows Media Uploads

Comment: Can't find it in the WP plugins directory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try creating a public account without a password and tweak WP a little to have that user always logged in?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use the following plugins:
gravity forms (one of the best, but not free)
post from site - http://redradar.net/2010/07/post-from-site-v2-0-1/
quick post widget - http://www.famvanakkeren.nl/downloads/quick-post-widget/

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that does exactly that thing:

> Anonymous Posting plugin allows anonymous user to write their own posts using special page, no access to WP panel is needed.
>   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anon-posting/

Comment: looks outdated, I'm not going to try