# Which WP plugin for enabling users add posts without registration?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know which WP plugin should I choose to allow every user who come to my page to add a post to my page form the frontend.

He just click on a button add a new post or something like that. Than a form appear and he inserts the title and uploads an image.

After that its published as a post.

Is there a solution like this available for WP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this duplicate thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042654/plugins-for-wordpress-that-allow-anonymous-users-to-post-entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, there is no existing plugin doing it as you need. Even if it existed, I wouldn't recommend it's use for security reasons; it is hard to follow every uses and make sure visitors would post the way you want.

You are definitely better to code it by your own, and it's quite simple using the [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function. This function will work anywhere you put it inside Wordpress (no need to build a plugin from scratch), so a simple form with validation would make it.

Hope it guides you on what you're looking for.